# Orthogonal complement of finite free modules

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be an integral domain (can assume it to be a regular $\mathbb{C}$-algebra), $M$ a finite-dimensional, free $A$-module and $N$ finite dimensional, free submodule of $M$. Does there exist a second submodule $M' \subset M$ such that $M' \cap N=\emptyset$ and $M' \oplus N=M$?

Comment: When talking about free modules not over a field, the usual term is "rank", not "dimension".

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not true.  For instance, in the case that $M=A$ has rank $1$ and $N\subset M$ is a nonzero proper submodule, then any nonzero submodule $M'\subseteq M$ has nonzero intersection with $N$ (if $0\neq a\in N$ and $0\neq b\in M'$, then $0\neq ab\in N\cap M'$).